# Bathtub Leak at the seal

Tags: bathtub, leaking, seal

Our 2nd floor bathtub was leaking due to old pipes, so we replaced the whole thing: New tub, new shower, new pipes, new surround. We still have the ceiling cut away under the tub from the water damage, because now the new tub is leaking. Not with every use, not continuously, but occasionally. To my untrained eye, (and reaching up there to feel for water) it seems to be an issue with the seal between the tub and the drain pipes.

Is this an easy diy fix or do I need to get the contractor back in to take care of it?

Comment: Personally, I'd have the contractor back (and not pay him anything to do it).  It should not leak out of the gate.

Comment: You hired someone to put it in, so they should indeed fix it so it does not leak.

Answer (score 6):

I would document the leaking when it does accrue, take pictures and date them. Get the contractor back to fix it. If you try to tighten up the fittings and it ends up being more than that,like a crack or chip, the contractor could say you damaged it so just have him do it. There is usually a warranty so it shouldn't be costing you anything for him to fix it.